# How to enable incremental builds for VS 2013 with CMake and long target names?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have a CMake project with a rather long target name (let's say `RatherLongLibraryName` which is 21 characters long) that I use to generate a Visual Studio solution. In my continuous integration setup this solution is regenerated each build after the CMake cache has been cleared. After the first build (second build, third build and so on) I get the following warning:

```
[...]\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(388,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (RatherLongLibraryName.dir\Release\) contains files shared from another project (RatherLongLibraryName.vcxproj)).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
```

In the warning, the projectname `RatherLongLibraryName.vcxproj` will be added in the parenthesis for each build. So for the third build, there will be two `.vcxproj`s mentioned there. And, lo and behold, the rebuild behavior is indeed incorrect: The library is rebuilt every time.

After a little digging I found that inside the build directory there is a `RatherLongLibraryName.dir\Debug\RatherLo.<first-8-GUID-chars>.tlog` directory. Each time I regenerate the solution, the GUID of the target `RatherLongLibraryName` changes, which leads to an additional directory `RatherLo.<first-8-GUID-chars>.tlog` which causes Visual Studio to complain with the above warning.

Since this problem doesn't exist with shorter target names I played around with the length and found out that when a target name is longer than **16 characters** Visual Studio switches the format of the `*.tlog` directory (from `targetname.tlog` to `<first-8-chars-of-target-name>.<first-8-GUID-chars>.tlog`). Since there now is an additional `tlog` directory a complete rebuild is triggered.

So, my question is: How do I allow incremental builds for long target names in a Visual Studio solution that is frequently regenerated by CMake?

---

**Workaround**: I worked around the issue for a time by simply shortening my target names, but this is just plain ugly. It works though.

Comment: I'll add my current solution as answer but won't accept it right away in case something better comes along.

Comment: Nice detective work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to fix the GUID in the `CMakeLists.txt`. That way, the GUID matches for each solution generation and only one `.tlog` directory is created. This seems to not confuse Visual Studio and the builds happen incrementally, as was intended.

To do this, you have to set a cache variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the project:

```
set( RatherLongLibraryName_GUID_CMAKE <generated GUID> CACHE INTERNAL "remove this and Visual Studio will mess up incremental builds")
```

[Further documentation of the set command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html).

I'm not exactly sure what this will do for non Visual Studio builds, but my guess is that the value will simply be ignored.